# Create a Cross-Container Tab Index

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm facing a little problem I can't seem to solve.
The problem is in an WinForm I have several containers (TabControls, Panels, ...).

The Tab-order within the controls work fine (of course). But now a customer asked to change the taborder to jump from a textbox in the first container (current tabindex 0,0,1) to a control in another container (current tabindex 0,1,0,1).

My first approach was setting the tabindex of the second to 0,0,1,1 but with no effect. The tab jumps from 0,0,1 to 0,0,2.

I tried a couple of other combinations too but with no result.

Can anybody provide me with hints how I might solve this problem?

PS: the 0,0,0 stands for the containers that contain the control just in case this is not clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could work with the [Leave event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.leave.aspx) of that Control, and manually set focus in the code behind to do this.

```
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    textBox2.Focus();
}
```

Comment: Simple but effective. Thanks a lot

Comment: You could clean up a bit though, and only go to the next textbox if the "TAB" key is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the TAB key, it's better to not use the `Leave event`
It will create some bad redirections if you change with your mouse for example.

Better override [ProcessCmdKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.form.processcmdkey(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Here is a good solution :**

```
 protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
        {
            bool baseResult = base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);

            //if key is tab and TextBox1 is focused then jump to TextBox2
            if (keyData == Keys.Tab && TextBox1.Focused)
            {
                TextBox2.Focus();
                return true;
            }
            else if (keyData == Keys.Tab && TexBox2.Focused)
            {
                TextBox3.Focus();
                return true;
            }
                return baseResult;
        }
```

Hope it helped.